# A variável de um vetor esta substituindo a de outro vetor, apenas em um caso especifico

Tags: c

Quando vetor3 recebe 5 de tamanho, o vetor2[0] irá receber, mesmo já tendo um valor atribuído e sem nenhum comando para isso acontecer, ele recebe o valor de vetor3[4]. Sendo quer isso ocorre apenas quando o vetor3 tem tamanho igual a 5. Alguém sabe o motivo.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int um=0, dois=0, tres=0, c=0;
    
    printf("tamanho vetor2: ");
    scanf("%d", &dois);
    printf("valores: \n");
    int vetor2[dois-1];
    for(c=0; c <= (dois-1); c++) vetor2[c] = 0;
    for (c = 0; c <= dois-1; c++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor2[c]);
    }
    
    //printf("vetor2[0]:%d\n", vetor2[0]);
    
    printf("tamanho vetor3: ");
    scanf("%d", &tres);
    printf("valores: \n");
    int vetor3[tres-1];
    for(c=0; c <= (tres -1); c++) vetor3[c] = 0;
    for (c = 0; c <= (tres-1); c++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor3[c]);
    }
    printf("vetor2[0]: %d, vetor3[%d]: %d",vetor2[0], tres-1, vetor3[tres-1]);
    printf("\n");
    
}
```

É necessário colocar o valor 5, quando for solicitado o tamanho do vetor3, para ver esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código tem uma falha: você cria o `vetor2` com tamanho `dois-1` e depoisacessa o vetor na posição `dois-1` no loop for, isso deveria ser uma falha de segmentação, mas, não sei porquê, nem para você nem para mim houve essa falha de segmentação, mas sim uma falha de resultado para o `vetor3` com tamanhos multiplus de 4+1 como 5, 9, 13 e diante. O problema de alocação de tamanho vale para o `vetor3`.

Se criar os vetores com os tamanhos sem diminuir 1, funcionará.

Uma dica: não precisa atibuir valores aos elementos do vetor se for pegar os valores da entrada padrão.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int um=0, dois=0, tres=0, c=0;
    
    printf("tamanho vetor2: ");
    scanf("%d", &dois);
    printf("valores: \n");
    int vetor2[dois];
    // for(c=0; c <= (dois-1); c++) vetor2[c] = 0; // não precisa devido ao loop abaixo
    for (c = 0; c <= dois-1; c++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor2[c]);
    }
    
    //printf("vetor2[0]:%d\n", vetor2[0]);
    
    printf("tamanho vetor3: ");
    scanf("%d", &tres);
    printf("valores: \n");
    int vetor3[tres];
    // for(c=0; c <= (tres -1); c++) vetor3[c] = 0; // não precisa devido ao loop abaixo
    for (c = 0; c <= (tres-1); c++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor3[c]);
    }
    printf("vetor2[0]: %d, vetor3[%d]: %d",vetor2[0], tres-1, vetor3[tres-1]);
    printf("\n");
    
}
```